# Accessing custom attributes on a custom field in JFormField

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I've created a custom field type in Joomla and need to pass parameters to it. For example, my JForm XML file looks like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_gallery/models/fields">

        <field name="images" 
            type="MultiImage"                         
                    label="Images"
            description="" 

            imagetable="#__gallery_images" 
            imagedir="../images/gallery/originals/"                        

                /> 

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

And I want to access the `imagetable` and `imagedir` attributes within my custom field:

```php
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldMultiImage extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'MultiImage';

    public function getInput() {

        //this is where i want to access it
        $input = $this->imagetable;     

        return $input;
    }
}
```

I assumed you just used `$this->attributename`, and when I `var_dump($this)` I can see the attributes are defined but they are `:protected`.

I would appreciate some help on this :)

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are so close! Try this and let me know if it works for you, because it works for me. (Joomla 2.5.6)

```
echo $this->element['imagedir'];
echo $this->element['imagetable'];
```